# Remove Black Outline of Input buttons in IE 9 using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Is it possible to remove the annoying black border that IE 9 puts around submit buttons?

This only occurs when the form is in focus.

IE 9:

[IE 9 http://olokoo.com/sandbox/ie.jpg](http://olokoo.com/sandbox/ie.jpg)

FireFox

[Firefox http://olokoo.com/sandbox/firefox.jpg](http://olokoo.com/sandbox/firefox.jpg)

Comment: Those focus lines are there for a reason.  It helps users know that they can hit enter or space bar.  Not so "annoying" if you ask me...

Comment: I have added my own borders that become visible when focused using jquery. The black 2px border just doesnt go with my design, i know that people like to know when to they can hit enter..

Comment: have you tried `border:none;` and/or `outline:none;` ?

Comment: Can you post your code?  I don't see any black border here: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/PMmAn/

Comment: After playing around with the code you posted at jsfiddle, I realized that the only difference between my code and your code was <!DOCTYPE html> and <META http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> so when I switched mine out for yours, It worked perfectly. I'm not really sure why but it also changed the way padding was being handled but that is not really a problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Ian34 is you issue resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery if you want, but adding the following to your CSS should fix it

```
input[type=submit] { border:none !important; }
```

**//edit per your comment**

Depending on if you want to use HTML5 or not, you need to make sure you've set up the DOCTYPE and meta tags correctly:

*HTML5 setup:*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Example paragraph</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

*For HTML4 setup examples see:* [**W3School**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the border from the buttons with jQuery, something like this should work:

```
$(":button").css({border-width:"0px"});
```